# How to get normal rank "instance of"(wdt:P31) entry on Wikidata SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get Normal Rank "instance of"(wdt:P31) entry but the query results with only Preferred Rank result.
Following is the code to get "instance of"(wdt:P31) of "Tokyo"(wd:Q1490).
This code will return only wd:P515(city).

```
SELECT ?instanceLabel WHERE {
  wd:Q1490 wdt:P31 ?instance .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }   
}
```

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1490

We can check the record of wd:Q1490 and we can find not only wd:P515 but also some other. wd:P515 is preferred rank and other are Normal. How can I include all of "instance of" entries on my query result?

Comment: `SELECT ?instanceLabel WHERE {
  wd:Q1490 p:P31/ps:P31 ?instance .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }   
}`